# error: exportArchive: Code signing "MyFramework.framework" failed in fastlane build

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning-profile, fastlane, fastfile

Archive succeeded but export failed through Fastlane build.

[image]

But the same export is working fine through Xcode because Xcode is not even asking for MyFrameworkIOS to sign.
[image]

I have two ways in mind to get this resolution:

1. How to avoid signing MyFrameworkIOS when building through fastlane in build machine? Because as you can see above, when building through xcode then MyFrameworkIOS signing is not required at all.
2. If we need to sign it then how to sign MyFrameworkIOS which is our own Framework created separately and being embedded in MyProject?

Fastfile:

```
default_platform(:ios)
platform :ios do
  desc "Build the application"
  lane :testflightbuild do
    build_app(
     scheme: "MyScheme",
     workspace: "MyProject.xcworkspace",
     export_method: "app-store",
     export_options: {
     
     },
     include_bitcode: true
    )
  end
end
```

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Have you found the solution? If yes, could you please share it?